# Executing reckonTagCreate from gitlab ci with authentication failure

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have setup my CI so that I can manually create a release-tag when all tests succeeds for a new commit on master branch. For this I have created a manual step in the CI config like so:

```
.release-template:
  stage:
    releasing
  dependencies:
    - assemble
  script:
    - ./gradlew reckonTagPush -Preckon.scope=$scope -Preckon.stage=$stage -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.username=$GIT_USER -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.password=$GIT_PASSSWORD
  only:
    - master
  when: manual #ONLY MANUAL RELEASES, ONLY FROM MASTER

release-major:
  extends: .release-template
  variables:
    scope: major
    stage: final

release-minor:
  extends: .release-template
  variables:
    scope: minor
    stage: final

release-patch:
  extends: .release-template
  variables:
    scope: patch
    stage: final
```

This setup fails with an authentication error.

```
Execution failed for task ':reckonTagPush'.
> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab-ci-token@gitlab.com/<group>/<project>.git: not authorized
```

I am running this on gitlab.com on a shared runner.

The username and password are configured in gitlab ci variables for the project. When running this locally inside the same docker image that is used in the gitlab runner, it works fine. So there must be something special about the way the gitlab runner is executing the gradle tasks, or communicating with the gitlab git repo.

Comment: What is `reckon`, is that a built-in Gradle command?

Comment: reckon is a gradle plugin that uses git tags for versioning. This means that there is no version field in the gradle script, and hence no "bump version" commits. Only tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with access to pushing to the git repo by adding the following script :

```
 script:
    - url_host=`git remote get-url origin | sed -e "s/https:\/\/gitlab-ci-token:.*@//g"`
    - git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:$GIT_TOKEN@$url_host"
    - ./gradlew reckonTagPush -Preckon.scope=$scope -Preckon.stage=$stage -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.username="$GIT_USER" -Dorg.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.password="$GIT_TOKEN"
```

The notably changes here are setting the git remote url, as well as surrounding the gitlab ci variables with " when passing them to the reckon plugin